# Using DataAnnonations constraints on a Data Transfer Object(dto) Model to update a Domain Model

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

i have a question.
i have a form which returns a CustomerDto model when submitted, i want to add some constraints like required, minlength etc to perform validation on the form, but the domain model class(Customer) that the customerDto model would map the form data to when saving does not have these data annotations constraints, is it possible for me to
add these constraints in the CustomerDto model only and perform server side validation with them and then map the CustomerDto model to the Customer model(domain) which do not have these constraints?

I do not want to alter the existing database structure by adding constraints to the Domain model customer class, but i still want to use CustomerDto model class to perform server side validation

Comment: of course it's possible but bear in mind that the domain model should protect it's invariants and should make sure the domain object is always in a valid state. so if all of your validations take place in CustomerDto, some other part of the code could potentially manipulate your domain model bypassing the validations and could create invalid customers. so i would suggest putting validation code to the core (domain).

Comment: @MarkusS. thanks...i'm grateful